# How to set custom icon to custom token?

Tags: tokens

I had created a bep20 token contract and deployed it on the BSC testnet.
But as it is a new custom token, so it has no icon.
I had a hard time finding a way to set the custom icon to the custom token but I didn't.
So I decided to ask the method to the community.
Please anyone help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot (and shouldn't) set an icon to tokens on the blockchain as that would cost a ridiculous amount of gas to do. Instead, indexing services like Etherscan add logos to reputable tokens. So unfortunately, what you say is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And what about tokens have their own icons? Do they pay that ridiculous amount of gas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is a Guide to add logo to new token in Trust wallet
https://community.trustwallet.com/t/how-to-submit-a-token-logo/3863
but you need

- 2500 holder
- 5000 transactions
- social media presence
- website or white paper

and here is the guide for Ether Scan
https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-add-an-image-logo-to-your-crypto-token/

and this is an easy way to add image to the token . note that it will work only on your device . its just like edit the sitting in your local device .
https://vittominacori.github.io/watch-token/

but its something .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you mean only I can see the token logo after register on indexing sites? Anybody can't see the logo after I register the token logo?